# How to prevent the use of shared memory / pointers using multiple class instances in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, class, pointers

How can I prevent the creation of shared memory between multiple instances of a class?

Or, how can I prevent the following?

**mwe.py**

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

class Entry:
  content = []

sample = {
    'C1':  Entry(),
    'C2':  Entry(),
    }

sample['C1'].content.append('test')

print(sample['C2'].content)
```

```sh
$ ./mwe.py 
['test']
```

Comment: Indeed! Thanks a lot!